# My foreground notification service doesn't work properly if i change my package prefix name in putExtra Method why?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, foreground-service, foregroundnotification

I used the Foreground Service code from Floating Window in localazy.com. My foreground Service didn't send correct codes to the onStartCommand() after I change the package prefix name that they in given in their code in the putExtra Method it always sends null instead of sending the EXIT and NOTE command. Actually, what is the use of the package prefix in the key name? Why did this problem happen?.

```
package com.krithik.floatingnote.service

import android.app.*
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.krithik.floatingnote.R


const val INTENT_COMMAND = "com.localazy.quicknote.COMMAND"
const val INTENT_COMMAND_EXIT = "EXIT"
const val INTENT_COMMAND_NOTE = "NOTE"

private const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GENERAL = "note_general"
private const val CODE_FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 1
private const val CODE_EXIT_INTENT = 2
private const val CODE_NOTE_INTENT = 3


class FloatingService : Service() {


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null


    /**
     * Remove the foreground notification and stop the service.
     */
    private fun stopService() {
        stopForeground(true)
        stopSelf()
    }


    /**
     * Create and show the foreground notification.
     */
    private fun showNotification() {

        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val exitIntent = Intent(this, FloatingService::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(INTENT_COMMAND, INTENT_COMMAND_EXIT)
        }

        val noteIntent = Intent(this, FloatingService::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(INTENT_COMMAND, INTENT_COMMAND_NOTE)
        }

        val exitPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, CODE_EXIT_INTENT, exitIntent, 0
        )

        val notePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                this, CODE_NOTE_INTENT, noteIntent, 0
        )

        // From Android O, it's necessary to create a notification channel first.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            try {
                with(
                        NotificationChannel(
                                NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GENERAL,
                                getString(R.string.notification_channel_general),
                                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                        )
                ) {
                    lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
                    manager.createNotificationChannel(this)
                }
            } catch (ignored: Exception) {
                // Ignore exception.
            }
        }

        with(
                NotificationCompat.Builder(
                        this,
                        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GENERAL
                )
        ) {
            setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
            setAutoCancel(false)
            setOngoing(true)
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_note_24)
            setContentIntent(notePendingIntent)
            addAction(
                    NotificationCompat.Action(
                            0,
                            getString(R.string.notification_exit),
                            exitPendingIntent
                    )
            )
            startForeground(CODE_FOREGROUND_SERVICE, build())
        }

    }


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        val command = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_COMMAND)
        Log.i("ServiceCommand", command.toString())
        // Exit the service if we receive the EXIT command.
        // START_NOT_STICKY is important here, we don't want
        // the service to be relaunched.
        if (command == INTENT_COMMAND_EXIT) {
            stopService()
            return START_NOT_STICKY
        }

        // Be sure to show the notification first for all commands.
        // Don't worry, repeated calls have no effects.
        showNotification()

        // Show the floating window for adding a new note.
        if (command == INTENT_COMMAND_NOTE) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Floating window to be added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }

        return START_STICKY
    }

}
```

````
package com.krithik.floatingnote

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.krithik.floatingnote.database.Note
import com.krithik.floatingnote.database.NoteDatabase
import com.krithik.floatingnote.database.NoteRepository
import com.krithik.floatingnote.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.krithik.floatingnote.service.FloatingService
import com.krithik.floatingnote.service.INTENT_COMMAND

import com.krithik.floatingnote.viewModel.NoteViewModel
import com.krithik.floatingnote.viewModel.NoteViewModelFactory
import com.krithik.floatingnote.viewModel.RecyclerViewAdapter

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), RecyclerViewAdapter.RowClickListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: RecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        startFloatingService()
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        val dao = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application).noteDao
        val repository = NoteRepository(dao)
        val factory = NoteViewModelFactory(repository)
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
        binding.noteViewModel = noteViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        noteViewModel.message.observe(this, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
                Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
        initRecyclerView()
        noteViewModel.noteList.observe(this, Observer {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })

    }


    private fun initRecyclerView() {
        binding.noteRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(this)
        binding.noteRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

    }

    override fun onDeleteNote(note: Note) {
        noteViewModel.deleteNote(note)
    }

    private fun Context.startFloatingService(command: String = "") {
        val intent = Intent(this, FloatingService::class.java)
        if (command.isNotBlank()) intent.putExtra(INTENT_COMMAND, command)
        Log.i("Command", INTENT_COMMAND + command)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            this.startForegroundService(intent)
        } else {
            this.startService(intent)
        }


    }
}
```
````

Comment: Hi, I posted this question. I used constants value like 
 const val INTENT_COMMAND = "com.localazy.quicknote.COMMAND"
const val INTENT_COMMAND_EXIT = "EXIT"
const val INTENT_COMMAND_NOTE = "NOTE"

if I change the package prefix name it didn't send the correct constant value to the onStartCommand function. I don't know why somebody please answer this.

Comment: i'm confused a little bit. you're mentioning 'package prefix name', is it meaning constant value or project package hierarchy?

Comment: in doucumentation actually its a string name : 
public Intent putExtra (String name, 
                CharSequence value)
Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll". 
I tried my package prefix name but it didn't work